# pyspark Structured streaming (2.4.2) - foreach sink

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I am running spark 2.4.2 on dataproc GCP and applying stateful aggregations to streaming IOT data with a watermark of 1 day as below :

```
csvDF = sqlcontext \
    .readStream \
    .option("sep", ",") \
    .option("checkpointLocation", "gs://bucket_name/checkpoint") \
    .schema(schema) \
    .csv(bucket_path)

df_aggregated = csvDF \
                .withWatermark("date_time","1 day") \
                .groupBy(
                    csvDF.unique_device_id) \
                .agg(
                    sum(col('overall_measure1')),
                    sum(col('overall_measure2')),
                    sum(col('overall_measure3'))
                   )

def process_row(row):
          if row['overall_measure1'] >= 10000 : 
               #Write a file with a custom message to the gcs bucket
          print(row)
          pass

query = (

        df_aggregated.writeStream \
        .foreach(process_row)
        .outputMode("complete")
        .start()
    )
```

My objective is to get the summed value for each row and check if any of the values (overall_measure1,overall_measure2,overall_measure3) go beyond a certain value , lets say 10000 .if so, i want to be able to write some custom message to my GCS bucket . I have tried the below , theres not enough documentation anywhere so i'd appreciate if anyone could let me know how to go about this .

**Problem faced** -  I am not able to capture the value using the foreach sink and my question isn't about how to write a custom file to the gcs bucket .

Comment: Have you looked at this: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#using-foreach-and-foreachbatch ? Try moving your if block inside the process method

Comment: not sure i understand...my if block is already inside the function and its not about the if block , its about being able to capture the values inside the process_row function which is what is not happening . And yes , of course i've looked at the documentation .